# ATMEGA32 Fuse bit settings, Low Fuse and High Fuse, 16MHz, External crystal?

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega

I am using `ATMEGA32` with Crystal `16MHz`.
I have written following code to generate `1kHz` wave.

I tried writing `Low- 0xFF` `High-0x99`
But I am unable to get `1kHz wave`. I am getting `250Hz wave`. instead of `1kHz`.

Please help.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL 
#include <avr/io.h> //io related 
#include <util/delay.h> //delay
#include "lcd.h" //custom lib for lcd
#include <stdlib.h> //for string handling
#ifndef sbit_h
#define sbit_h
int main(void)
{

    //All Declarations Go here.

   OCR0=p*127/100; //set pwm1 duty cycle
   OCR2=OCR0;      //set pwm2 duty cycle (Output compare register)

   while(1)
   { 
      if ((bit_is_set(PIND, 3 )))
       {
           pinChange(LED8,1); //Turn on solenoid valve
           pinChange(LED1,1);
           //PORTC|=(1<<PC3);
           _delay_ms(sq); //wait for squeeze time
           TCCR0 |= (1<<WGM00)|(1<<COM01)|(1<<WGM01)|(1<<CS01)|(1<<CS00); 
           //initialise timer in PWM mode 1kHz//cs00 and cs02
           _delay_us(500);//90 degree phase shift
           TCCR2 |= (1<<WGM20)|(1<<COM21)|(1<<WGM21)|(1<<CS22); //initialise timer2 in PWM mode 1kHz//CS22 for 1kHz
           _delay_ms(w1); //wait until weld time over
           TCCR0=0x00;  //stop PWM1
           TCCR2=0x00;  //Stop PWM2
           _delay_ms(h); //wait for hold time
           pinChange(LED8,0); //turn off solenoid valve
           pinChange(LED1,0);
           TCNT0=0x00; //Reset timer counter
           TCNT2=0x00; //reset timer counter
     }
}
```

Comment: Probably, the timer uses a divided clock as input and you can somehow configure the divisor. Have a look in your datasheet.

Comment: It was working Fine with previous ATMEGA32 chip which came with the Kit.
I never bothered to check/change the Fuse bits.
But, That one burned due to some problem. so I had to buy new one.
Code is same, Circuit is the same.
I am sure it has something to do with Fuse bit Settings.
I referred to datasheet and set 0xFF anf 0x99 as fuse bits according to datasheet. but, unfortunately, still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set clock selection `fuse bits` (and possibly clock divider) in the correct way? I'd start checking `CKSEL0...3` and `CKDIV8`.

By my experience, getting an exact multiple of the desired `time/frequency` is almost always based on a wrong clock setting.

Comment: I checked and double checked CKSEL0...3 should be 1111
CKDIV8 i have checked and it works good on simulator.
Just that it does not work as expected in real hardware.
I thought my oscillator has given up. I have replaced the Crystal too.

Comment: @AntarikshBahekar: You could narrow down the problem by temporarily using the internal 8MHz oscillator (low fuse 0xE4) and check if you get (half) the expected frequency that way. You could also just toggle an IO-Pin every second with a _delay_ms(1000) and verify that its really 1s. First, get your time-base right, then start PWN stuff.

Comment: @AntarikshBahekar: To verify if you set the clock source properly, you can disconnect the chrystal and check you output signal. If you're still getting 250Hz, the microcontroller is running on its internal clock.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem solved.
I changed the programmer.
Low fuse-0xFF High Fuse-0x99 worked.
I was writing those values but my programmer was unable to write it.


ATMega32 Does not have CKDIV8 Fuse